# New line in tooltip

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put some line breaks in my tooltip but something goes wrong. I tried to use `<br>` with `data-html="true"` but there are just `br` as string(insted new line). I have also tried `&#xA;` and `&#013;` but it works only for first linebreak(second and others don't works - browser ignores this char). How is it possible to get a few new lines in tooltip as `title`?

Comment: It's not. Whitespace is whitespace, and the browser will decide how to display the title.

Comment: @Pete I tried just press `enter` but works only for first line....

Comment: Show your code and perhaps we can tell why it isn't working otherwise paste your comment under the solution that says to use enter - don't direct it at me

Comment: <a href="http://google.com" title="Sample&#013;&#009; Text">Google</a>, its working.

Answer (score 0):

To give a line break in a tooltip simply use the enter key like the example below:

```html
<a href="http://google.com" title='Sample



text'>Google</a>
```

Comment: ...WHAT. Why this, HTML? Why not use something logical? Well, it works....

Comment: @Feathercrown Hahaha I know.. but that's the way it works..